# First connection org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm having problems with a server in Spring 4 and Mysql with Hibernate, Every first connection it is answering me   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

My properties.xml is:

```
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://mysql.******?reconnect=true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="****" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer"
            value="allow" />

        <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period" value="100" />
        <property name="c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
        <property name="c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
        <property name="c3p0.min_size" value="10" />
        <property name="c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Someone is having the same problem or knows a solution?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following JDBC url

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poc
```

poc is schema name

Comment: Well the url that I use in the real code is well formatted an it is able to connect, I'm using "***" in order to not put here the real url, But it can't be the problem

Comment: I realise that the problem is that I have multiples tomcat with the same war targetting to the same mysql, and then after one of them is restarted, the rest are unnable to acquire connection given the error that I explained...